# Which is best function available in c++ to convert SID to Account username?

Tags: c++, windows, api, sid

I have sids of user accounts like this
`S-1-5-21-4030387420-2927818341-1631038489-1001`
I want simple c++ function which will convert this sid to username.
if any of you have code for that then plz post

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: try using LookupAccountSid function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your friend - it takes a SID and turns it into a user name.  Warning, it can take some time to run.

If you have a text string containing the SID (as in your example above), you can use the [ConvertStringSidToSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert the string into a binary blob which can then be read by LookupAccountSid.

Comment: :Thank you for your answer, it would be better if you also provide code.